# jQuery alternatives to Highslide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dialog

Are there any robust jQuery alternatives to the JavaScript popup/lightbox library [Highslide](http://highslide.com/)? Highslide is too focused on the image gallery aspect and I'm just wondering if there are options.

I'm not looking for a triditional lightbox, rather floating/movable divs as in Highslide.

Comment: check : http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/ . A pretty robust lightbox solution that i used for my product.

Answer (score 1):

For lightboxes I've found that there is generally just one real candidate.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

It's extremely flexible content wise and lends itself really well to be styled in whatever way you like.. heh.

I can say from experience that the code in it is really robust. It's popular, well tested and maintained. I wouldn't go for anything else UNLESS I need more expansive image gallery options which it has some limited options to. But even then I'd at least considder extending fancybox first.

Comment: Note that it is not free for commercial projects

Comment: IF you're earning money with your project the 15 bucks for the licence is negligible. For that money I could work about 10 minutes for a customer.

Comment: @sg3s Licensing issues have little to do with cost.

Answer (score 0):

MopBox might work for you (not limited just to images, not focused on image galleries): http://www.mopstudio.jp/mopBox2demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you're looking for.

For large popup boxes I use [simpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). I started using it a little while ago and it has served all my purposes flawlessly.

For tooltips with a small amount of content in them, I use [TooltipsY](http://tooltipsy.com/). Which is an EXCELLENT way to do tooltips.

Those two jQuery plugins can serve pretty much any purpose you could want regarding popup boxes.

**Edit:** Nevermind, I just found out what you meant by dragging. Yeah, these can't drag and drop, I've never found a purpose for that before.

Comment: Actually they don't necessarily need to be draggable, just the popup should open where was invoked, or have positioning options.

Comment: Both my suggestions can be positioned wherever you want them to pop up. Have a look

Comment: TooltipsY looks great, I will be using it for tooltips. But for larger content is there anything more...robust than simpleModal?

Comment: Well, you tell me. Look at my website. Click the button I added to show you simpleModal. It says "Click here to open up the Modal". Here is the link: http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/ultimate.html